# How to reset Windows 8 theme settings, using safe mode, not being able to access normal mode?

Tags: windows

After changing Windows 8 theme settings, I am unable to login into my account. When I try to login into my account, I get farted out back to the login screen. What I am supposed to do to fix this problem?

Comment: What theme settings did you change? This kind of change should not prevent you from logging in ...

Comment: I've changed the desktop theme in Personalization window. It seems that the theme was corrupted and Windows didn't manage to jump back to a default theme on it's own. I've posed the fix below.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1. When you're at the login screen, click on the "power icon," located in the right lower corner of your screen. From the pop-out list, while **holding SHIFT, click the "Restart"** list-item.
2. Three options will appear on a blue background. Choose **Troubleshoot**.
3. More options will appear on the screen. From those options select **Startup Settings**.
4. A restart button should appear, click on the **Restart button**.
5. Your device should restart and a numbered list should appear on the screen. To select the Safe-Mode boot press the **5 or F5** on your keyboard.
6. Your device should boot into the desired start-mode. Choose **Search** the Menu Bar. Type **run** into the search box, and start the program.
7. A window with an input should appear on the screen. Type **msconfig** into the input and press enter.
8. Choose the "Services" tab located at the top of the window frame, near the window border.
9. A list of services should appear. Find service named "Themes," and **uncheck it**.
10. Press the **Apply** and **OK**.
11. The window should disappear. Now **restart** your device, boot into the Normal-Mode.
12. Your device should reboot and enter the Normal-Mode. Login into your account.
13. You should be logged into your account. Now repeat the steps from 6, to and including 10, but this time **check** the themes service. When you're done, follow the steps below.
14. The window should disappear. Now click right mouse button on the desktop background and select **Personalize**.
15. A window with themes should appear on the screen. Choose one of the Windows default themes from the list, and apply the settings. This was the last step.